# Understanding Secondary Log Hard Disk Impact on Write Speed and Data Integrity After Power Outage

Tags: database, ssd, hard-drive

I've recently come across the notion that a secondary log hard disk can be employed to enhance write operation speed in a database system. I find this concept intriguing but am struggling to grasp the mechanics behind it. Could someone shed light on why a secondary log hard disk is effective in accelerating write operations?

Moreover, I've stumbled upon the statement that both SSDs and HDDs can retain all data written, even after a power outage. This caught my attention, and I'm curious to understand the mechanisms that allow both storage types to maintain data integrity post-power outage. If anyone could provide insights into this aspect as well, it would greatly contribute to my understanding.

Comment: How is this security related?

Comment: If you edited the question and posted it on SuperUser/Computer Science SE it might find its' audience there (perhaps)

Comment: The mechanisms of data storage on SSDs and HDDs are well documented. Two drives can accept writes at twice the speed of a single drive, given unique and similar data paths within the system they are operating within. That said, this question lacks evidence of self-effort, research into established and well-documented systems, and other factors that indicate it should have been closed rather than being migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Your storage device be it hdd,sdd, nvme, or etc has a max mb/s it can handle.  It also has a maximum number of concurrent request it can handle.

For example a SATA 3 connection maxes around 550mb/s, and that is assume your storage device can handle that.

Now if you have 2 SATA 3 devices each cable can handle 550mb/s and therefore now you have 1100mb/s total bandwidth.

Therefore, if you have your OS and log files competing for the same bandwidth they will have to take turns and both will be slower because of this completion.

Think of it this way if 10 people go into a store and start asking 1 store employee question each of the 10 customers will have to wait there turn and it will take longer.  Now if you have 10 employees each customer will have a one on one experience.